# Validation messages into Directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying do a small reusable component in AngularJS using directives.
I have made good progress but I have a problem with the validations. For example the required validation not working. I think is "binding" issue.

My HTML code: also in http://jsfiddle.net/pQwht/17/

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
<form ng-controller="Ctrl"
  id="paymentCallForm"
  action="#"
  name="paymentCallForm">
  <table>
   <tr tdfield 
      labelname="Primary Account Number:" 
      fieldname="primaryAccountNumber"
      title="Primary title" 
      >
    </tr>  
  </table>
```

My directive script:

```
 angular.module('myApp').directive('tdfield', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace:false,
    transclude: false,
    scope: { labelname: '@', fieldname: '@', title: '@'},
    templateUrl:'element.html'
  };
 });
```

My element.html code:

```
 <td id="lbl_paymentReference" class="formInputLabelWrapper">{{labelname}}</td>
 <td class="formInputTextWrapper">
   <input id="{{fieldname}}"
     name="{{fieldname}}"
     title="{{title}}" 
     class="large empty"  
     required>
<span data-ng-show="paymentCallForm.{{fieldname}}.$error.required"
    class="error">Error</span></td>
```

Comment: Your <table does not have a closing >

Comment: Thanks Ketan, was a typing error. In the jsfiddle is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved this, but for what a price. There is a number of issues and angular related among them. I may not recall all, so here is the working example https://github.com/yaroslav-ulanovych/soq16245177.

When you define `scope` parameter like `scope: { labelname: '@', fieldname: '@', title: '@'},` (with an object as a value), that creates an isolated scope, which means not inherited from parent one's. Therefore here `ng-show="paymentCallForm.{{fieldname}}.$error.required"` is no access to the form. As a workaround `ng-show="$parent.paymentCallForm.{{fieldname}}.$error.required"`, but I didn't check whether your inputs are published in the form in case of the isolated scope. Or `scope: true` and inject attributes into the scope manually.

```
compile: function() {
    return {
        pre: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.fieldname = attr.fieldname;
        }
    }
}
```

Note on using prelink function, so that it's called before children are linked.

Next `ng-show` will actually use not interpolated expression and there is obviously no property named `{{fieldname}}` in the form. That is fixed in later versions of Angular, don't know when exactly, cause I'm using master.

But what is not fixed is `ngModelController`. It gets it's name very early so publishes itself on the form under wrong one. I had to fix that myself, good that there is only one line to do that, in file `src/ng/directive/input.js`.

```
// add
modelCtrl.$name = attr.name;
// before this
formCtrl.$addControl(modelCtrl);
```

Comment: Yaroslav, for use angular 1.1.1 in the element.html I used <span data-ng-show="form['\{\{fieldname\}\}'].$error.required" class="error">Error</span>

Comment: That works, cause both input and span use the same field name which is `{{fieldname}}`, not `primaryAccountNumber`. If you add the second row in the table, you see that it's input is ignored and the first input controls both spans.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a controller attached to your view. The form object will be attached to property with the id of the form on `$scope` object of this controller. Once you add that, I think it will start showing up.