# Dynamic ng-model names in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a form that allows a person object with fields for name and age to be appended to an array in Angularjs, but I can't get the field names to render properly. Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
  %tr
    %td{ 'ng-repeat' => 'h in maintitles' }
      %input{ :type => 'text', :value => '{{h.name}}', 'ng-model' => 'newPerson.' + '{{h.name}}' }
    %td
      %button{ 'ng-click' => 'addItem(newItem)' } Add
```

(The haml does compile correctly -- each input field has an `ng-model` attribute of `newPerson.{{h.name}}`, and the `value` field properly renders as the value of `{{h.name}}`, not the text '{{h.name}}' -- so the issue is definitely in the javascript.)

If I manually name each field, e.g.:

```
  %tr
    %td{ 'ng-repeat' => 'h in maintitles' }
      %input{ :type => 'text', :value => '{{h.name}}', 'ng-model' => 'newPerson.name' }
    %td{ 'ng-repeat' => 'h in maintitles' }
      %input{ :type => 'text', :value => '{{h.name}}', 'ng-model' => 'newPerson.age' }
    %td
      %button{ 'ng-click' => 'addItem(newItem)' } Add
```

then everything works as expected.

How do I get Angular to let me use variables in ng-model directives?

---

*Edit:* Based on Yaroslav's answer, I addressed this by creating a clone of the `maintitles` array with an empty data field to hold new values:

```
function AdminItemCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.titlename = $routeParams.itemType;

    $http.get('/data/' + $scope.titlename + 'items.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.maintitles = data.titles;
        $scope.main = data.data;
        $scope.emptyItem = angular.copy($scope.maintitles);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.emptyItem.length; i++) {
            delete $scope.emptyItem[i].editable;
            $scope.emptyItem[i].data = '';
        }

        $scope.cleanEmpty = angular.copy($scope.emptyItem);
    });

    $scope.addItem = function(newItem) {
        var newObject = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < newItem.length; i++)
            newObject[newItem[i].name] = newItem[i].data;

        $scope.main.push(newObject);
        $scope.emptyItem = angular.copy($scope.cleanEmpty);
    };
}
```

then in the HAML:

```
  %tr
    %td{ 'ng-repeat' => 'h in emptyItem' }
      %input{ :type => 'text', :placeholder => '{{h.name}}', 'ng-model' => 'h.data' }
    %td
      %button{ 'ng-click' => 'addItem(emptyItem)' } Add
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short Angular doesn't support this. `NgModelController` gets it's name before it is interpolated, so is published under the wrong one. There is an open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404) (hanging for 7 months now). I had to fix Angular a bit to get it working. I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245177/validation-messages-into-directive-angularjs/16250197#16250197) where you can read some details. Also there is a [working example with fixed Angular](https://github.com/yaroslav-ulanovych/soq16245177).